# Cohomology of structure sheaf of abelian variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, sheaf-cohomology, abelian-varieties

Let $X$ be an abelian variety over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $n$. Consider the structure sheaf $O_X$. It's Euler characteristic is zero, because $\chi(O_X)= (O_X^n)/n!$. And the self intersection of $O_X$ is 0. But is there some way to compute the $h^i(X,O_X)$? If the dimension $n=2$, then since $h^0=h^2=1$, we get $h^1=2$. What about for n>2? Is there some way to check this dimension?

Comment: For an abelian variety $X$ of dimension $n$ the cotangent sheaf is trivial $\Omega^1_X \cong \mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus n}$. Hence, using the symmetries of Hodge numbers,  you can compute $h^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=h^0(X,\Omega^i_X)=h^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus \binom{n}{i}})=\binom{n}{i}$

Comment: @Daniele A In char $p$, do we always have Hodge symmetry for smooth projectives?